# how to set row number in grid view

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to set number of row in data grid view (like identity in sql) in winforms. i am dynamically adding columns and rows in grid view. any idea.

Comment: Why not just do that in your data, and let the `GridView` display it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To display text in the row header you can use the `Row.HeaderCell.Value` as shown below:

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
                         DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView gridView = sender as DataGridView;
    if (null != gridView)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in gridView.Rows)
        {
            gridView.Rows[r.Index].HeaderCell.Value = 
                                (r.Index + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This only displays the row number of the new row when the user begins typing in it. Not sure if there is a simple way of always showing the row number on the new row.

> > > > Another best way for asp.net application.Here is a link    http://www.devcurry.com/2010/01/add-row-number-to-gridview.html

Just add the following tags to your  section of your GridView

```
<Columns>                       
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RowNumber">   
         <ItemTemplate>
                 <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>   
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     ...
</Columns>
```

Comment: i got error.problem is its showing 0 to 9 then 1,1,1...2.... its not showing 2th digit....

Comment: What if the AutoGenerateColumn is set to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
//You can also use below code

this.DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cell[0].value =e.RowIndex +1;
//get total number of rows

this.DataGridView1.Rows.Count;
```

**Method 2:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < SensorGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   DataGridViewRowHeaderCell cell = SensorGridView.Rows[i].HeaderCell;
   cell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
      SensorGridView.Rows[i].HeaderCell = cell;
}
```

**Method 3:**

```
void GridView_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
   this.GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value 
    = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: i got error.problem is its showing 0 to 9 then 1,1,1...2.... its not showing 2th digit....

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this way. Build a datatable first and then bind to grid like below

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
Datacolumn dc = new Datacolumn("ID");
Datacolumn dc1 = new Datacolumn("col1");

Datarow dr = tbl.NewRow();

dr[dc] = "123";
dr[dc1] = "SomeData";

tbl.Rows.Add(dr);

DataGridView.DataSource = tbl;
```